# Large() function returning text value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I managed to use a multiple criteria `large()` function in Excel.
For example, I identified the biggest value for a

- `Criteria 1` = `Man`
- `Criteria 2` = `Small`
- `Criteria 3` = `Red`

which is `200`.
Based on this, how can I retrieve the `Name` of the person gathering all those criterias, which is `Garry` ?
In another way, is there a `large()` function for text values ?

[image]

Comment: Use FILTER() if you have Office 365.  Otherwise you will need to use Large to use in MATCH to return the relative row number to INDEX.

Comment: Further to Scott's comment, if you have O365 then `FILTER()` makes this really easy.  If not, it can be done but it will be a rather long formula.  Also, is there a reason you are using `LARGE()` and not `MAX()`?  The use case for `LARGE()` is to return the *n*-th largest value or an array of *n* largest values.  If you are trying to return multiple names if there is a "tie" for the largest value that meets all the criteria, then you really, really want FILTER in O365.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `J2`:

```
=@SORT(FILTER(D2:E4,MMULT(N(A2:C4=G2:I2),{1;1;1})=3),2)
```